# Use HTTP proxy to connect to a web socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send a json through a web socket. The web socket has to be accessed through a HTTP Proxy.I tried using tyrus but it didn't work for proxy. Can you suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: You are doing plain sockets, not web sockets. Please check what you really  want to do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Modified the question

Comment: can you put some code of what failed.?

Comment: I have no idea what you have tried and what error messages you got and I don't know tyrus, but a short google points to [the documentation](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.7/user-guide.html#d0e1272) on how to use it with a proxy.  I also recommend you to read in-depth how question should be done if you want to get helpful answers.

Comment: @JafarAli As far as i know tyrus doesn't have a option of setting proxy, thus was unable to use it.

Comment: How hard can it be to [google for "tyrus websocket proxy"](https://www.google.com/?q=tyrus+websocket+proxy) and use the first hit? That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Tyrus client supports traversing proxies, but it is Tyrus specific feature and its configuration is shown in the following code sample:

```
ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://my.proxy.com:80");
```

Value is expected to be proxy URI. Protocol part is currently ignored, but must be present.

reference
[Client behind proxy](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.10/user-guide.html#d0e1323)